# Will 2.3 android app run on 2.2 if it doesnt use any extra APIs introduced in 2.3?

Tags: android, sdk, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to decide what target API should I choose to build my next android app. I know that Gingerbread was a major upgrade over Froyo and thus I want to use API 10(2.3.3). Also the report from Google tells me that Gingerbread 2.3.3 now has 61.5% of market share(http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

The thing is at this point of my project I am not very sure if the LocationManager and other API enchancement in Gingerbread will if of use, though my app will definitely use them. If I use 2.2 for development then I can target a greater audience.

My question is, will it be possible for 2.2(Froyo) users to install and run my 2.3.3(gingerbread) app if I dont use any new API's introduced in 2.3 SDK?

Edit : If the answer is no, what would you guys suggest me to do, being it March 2012 now and the pace with which updates are coming? Should developers start with minimum 2.3.3 now, seeing the bugfixes and enhancements been introduced in it, not to mention the top market shareholder.

Comment: I dont think the OS accepts it to be honest.

Comment: why are you using a 2.3 api if you're not using any 2.3 stuff?

Comment: I want to start with 2.3 just in case I have to use any APIs that will help me down the line. I am a beginner so cannot think too far to take that decision at the start of my project right now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could target 10 as API level, but define a minSdkVersion of 8 or so in your manifest. This will enable users of Froyo devices to install your app. But you have to ensure, that you don't use any API calls which are exclusive to API level 10. If you need to use functions introduced in API level 10 you should use them via reflection and either reimplement the missing functionality for pre API level 10 or notify the user of the missing functionaltiy.

Answer (score 2):

If you target your application at API 10, 2.2 users won't be able to install it, even if you don't use any new API methods.

If you keep your application at Android 2.2, 2.3 users will still be able to install and use it. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) for more.

Comment: In that case what would you suggest me to do. 2.2 or 2.3.3 ?

Comment: I would suggest 2.2, if you don't need any 2.3 features. If you turn out to need it down the line, you can always increase your API level.